# BeginConnect not firing up

Tags: c#, asyncsocket

Currently my code looks like this

```
    class XattyServer
    {
        private Socket _client;
        private Socket _worker;
        private ManualResetEvent _state;
        private string host;
        private int port;

        public XattyServer(string addr, int to)
        {
            _client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            host = addr;
            port = to;
        }

        public void Connect()
        {
            _client.BeginConnect(IPAddress.Parse(host), port, new AsyncCallback(AsyncBeginConnect), _client);
        }

        private void AsyncBeginConnect(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            _worker = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            Console.WriteLine("Connected to - {0}", host);
        }
    }

            XattyServer _server = new XattyServer("174.36.242.42", 10030);
            _server.Connect();

            Console.ReadLine();
```

The thing is BeginConnect looks like its never fired up since the Console.Wriline is never executed. The ip and the port are all correct tho.

Comment: How long did you wait? Test the connection with telnet.